# Governors Limits for reports

Tags: soql, reporting, governorlimits, exception

I am developing some kind of customized report functions using APEX and VF. As the conditions are quite complex and I need to query different objects even to get a number for one column for my report.

As there are thousands of records to process, whenever user click [Run Report], it starts to hit the exceptions.

I am thinking whether to use batch calls, but report is Real Time Function. So I am stuck on how to approach this issue.

Any input for walkaround?

any input will be so helpful for me.

```
 Object: Custom Objects used by my organization.

Error: Number of SOQL queries: 101 out of 100
```

Comment: are these custom reports or custom with apex ?

Comment: custom with apex.

Comment: Than some details on your code (queries!) , object count and specific errors may be very useful in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give any specific answers to a question without details, so some general things to think about:

**1.  Make sure you're using indexed fields as data filters**

Just like in SOQL, you have to pay some attention to how you structure your data queries, and anticipate in which way salesforce will try to look for your data. Full table scans are bad.

[check out the cheatsheet](https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_reportperformance_cheatsheet.pdf)

**2. Custom indexes**

Your data may have more unique fields or combinations of fields than are automatically indexed by salesforce, this could give you stronger options to use in your filters.

**3. Skinny tables**

Something you'll have to discuss with SF support, but they can create a dummy table/object which contains consolidated data from multiple objects. This is to increase performance of reports, but obviously needs to have valid arguments.

**4. Custom Apex/VF.**

Sometimes using Apex does have some benefits, and group by soql queries are a powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

Using read-only mode in Visualforce should help http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm

Writing efficient queries is going to be very important too.
Check out:
http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/04/designing-optimal-soql-queries-and-reports-for-your-salesforce-apps.html
and:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/dfc-wiki/en/images/0/0e/Db-query-search-optimization-cheat-sheet.pdf

However even so there are going to be limits on what you are going to be able to do in "real time" and you may have to consider pre-processing data into some form of reporting data object(s). This might be possible with an Analytic Snapshot, or you may need to write a Batch Apex process.

---

Judging from your updated question you are exceeding the maximum number of queries. It may be possible to join related objects in a single query thus reducing the number of queries you need to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @RemoteAction methods to query parts of the data, and then bring all of the data together using JavaScript. Using the @ReadOnly attribute on the @RemoteAction will allow you to retrieve 1,000,000 rows per call, which alone may be sufficient for your purposes. You will need to figure out how to optimize your queries, and rendering client-side can be a little tricky, so if you're not very experienced, I'd recommend jQuery to get you going. You also have to protect against cross-site scripting attempts, SOQL injection, and so on.